Handler for YAML file settings values
I am writing a program for calculating rocket engines and for its operation I store all the settings in files with the extension .yaml . To do this, I wrote this code and I want to get feedback and understand what can be improved or added in it and how best to implement the reset function in it.
Explanation of the code:
There are three classes in the code, the first and most important one responsible for interacting with files is Settings. It has several functions:

get_root_dir is a function responsible for getting the current directory of the settings file
record_date - responsible for receiving information that will be added to the file
configuration_file - gets the name of the settings file with which we will interact
record_settings - the function opens and writes data to a file
read_settings - function for reading and transferring data from the settings file

The second InjectorSettings class contains two functions that are responsible for passing the name of the configuration file and the data itself for writing or reading.
The third class ListNameSettingsFile will store the names of all configuration files that will be used by the program.
Code (settings.py):
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path
from enum import Enum

import yaml


class ListNameSettingsFile(Enum):
    """
    РУС: Список файлов конфигурации
    ENG: List of configuration files
    """
    LIST_NAME_SETTINGS_FILE = ["injector_settings"]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Settings(ABC):
    """
    РУС: Основной класс для обработки файлов конфигурации
    ENG: The main class for processing configuration files
    """
    @staticmethod
    def get_root_dir():
        """
        РУС: Директория установки ПО
        ENG: The software installation directory
        """
        return Path(__file__).absolute().parent

    @abstractmethod
    def record_date(self) -> dict:
        """
        РУС: Получение данных для загрузки в файл конфигурации
        ENG: Getting data to upload to a configuration file
        """
        raise NotImplementedError("Данные конфигурации не загружены")

    @abstractmethod
    def configuration_file(self) -> str:
        """
        РУС: Получение имени файла конфигурации
        ENG: Getting the name of the configuration file
        """
        raise NotImplementedError("Имя файла конфигурации не загружено")

    @property
    def record_settings(self) -> None:
        """
        РУС: Запись констант в файл конфигурации
        ENG: Writing constants to a configuration file
        """
        with open((self.get_root_dir() / "data").joinpath(self.configuration_file() + ".yaml"), "w") as outfile:
            new_dump = yaml.dump(self.record_date())
            outfile.write(new_dump)
        return None

    @property
    def read_settings(self) -> dict:
        """
        РУС: Чтение констант из файла конфигурации
        ENG: Reading constants from a configuration file
        """
        with open((self.get_root_dir() / "data").joinpath(self.configuration_file() + ".yaml"), "r") as stream:
            read_date = yaml.safe_load(stream)
        return read_date


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class InjectorSettings(Settings):
    """
    РУС: Класс констант для проведения расчетов
    ENG: A class of constants for performing calculations
    """
    laminar: float | None = None
    turbulent: float | None = None
    right_angle: float | None = None

    def record_date(self) -> dict:
        """
        РУС: Загрузка констант для расчетов
        ENG: Loading constants for calculations
        """
        injector_constants = {
            "reynolds": {"laminar": self.laminar, "turbulent": self.turbulent},
            "right_angle": self.right_angle,
        }
        return injector_constants

    def configuration_file(self) -> str:
        """
        РУС: Передача имени файла конфигурации
        ENG: Passing the name of the configuration file
        """
        return ListNameSettingsFile.LIST_NAME_SETTINGS_FILE.value[0]

injector_settings.yaml:
reynolds:
  laminar: 2000
  turbulent: 10000
right_angle: 90


I think your code structure and approach for handling YAML configuration files is generally sound (so congrats for that), but there might be several areas where improvements can be made. I'll break down my feedback into different sections:

general improvements.
specific code improvements

General Improvements
Error Handling:
It's a good idea to add error handling, especially when dealing with file operations. For example, you can add try-except blocks around file reading/writing operations to catch and log potential IO errors.
Type Annotations:
While your code does use type annotations, you can be more explicit in some places, such as the return type of read_settings. Currently, it returns dict, but if you know the specific structure, you can use Dict[str, Any] or a more specific type from typing.
Specific Code Improvements
Abstract Methods:
The record_date method might be better named get_data_for_recording or something more descriptive. "Date" could be misleading since it's more about getting data than just a date.
Similarly, consider renaming record_settings to something like save_settings to make its purpose clearer.
Path Handling:
You are currently using a data directory within your project’s root. It would be good to ensure this directory exists before attempting to write to it. You can add a check or create the directory if it doesn’t exist.
data_dir = self.get_root_dir() / "data"
data_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

YAML Dump Settings:
When dumping data into YAML, you can specify default_flow_style=False in yaml.dump to ensure that the YAML file is more human-readable (especially useful for larger data structures).
Singleton or Factory Pattern:
If you anticipate having multiple settings classes that follow a similar pattern, consider using a Factory Pattern to create instances based on file names or settings type.
Ideas for improvement
I think it could be useful to have some sort of reset function which can be used to revert the configuration to default settings.

Thank you for such a detailed answer! I also thought about creating a reset function, but I still can't figure out where it would be better to implement it.

GrajdeanuAlex - my implementation of the reset function. @alexandrov I didn't expect to see your related question here. Have you clarified all the points?

@AnnaBazueva Yes, of course
